# Unable to install package using docker : kpt not found or ambiguous repo/dir@version specify '.git' in argument

Tags: linux, docker, kpt

I am using below script and it giving me an error **#/bin/sh: 1: kpt: not found**

```
FROM nginx    
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install git
RUN apt -y install curl

# install kpt package
RUN mkdir -p ~/bin
RUN curl -L https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kpt/releases/download/v1.0.0-beta.1/kpt_linux_amd64 --output ~/bin/kpt && chmod u+x ~/bin/kpt
RUN export PATH=${HOME}/bin:${PATH}
RUN SRC_REPO=https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests
RUN kpt pkg get $SRC_REPO/tf-training@v1.1.0 tf-training
```

But if I create the image using

```
FROM nginx
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install git
RUN apt -y install curl
```

and perform

```
docker exec -it container_name bash
```

and manually do the task then I am able to install kpt package. Sharing below the screenshot of the process
[image]

The error changes if I provide the full path to /bin/kpt
**Error: ambiguous repo/dir@version specify '.git' in argument**

```
FROM nginx
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install git
RUN apt -y install curl
RUN mkdir -p ~/bin
RUN curl -L https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kpt/releases/download/v1.0.0-beta.1/kpt_linux_amd64 --output ~/bin/kpt && chmod u+x ~/bin/kpt
RUN export PATH=${HOME}/bin:${PATH}
# Below line of code is to ensure that kpt is installed and working fine
RUN ~/bin/kpt pkg get https://github.com/ajinkya101/kpt-demo-repo.git/Packages/Nginx
RUN SRC_REPO=https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests
RUN ~/bin/kpt pkg get $SRC_REPO/tf-training@v1.1.0 tf-training
```

What is happening when I am using docker and not able to install it?

Comment: Can you reconfigure `kpt` to write out plain-text error messages, rather than PNG files, and [edit] the question to include the actual text of the error?  This will be much easier to read and to search for later.

Comment: `export PATH=${HOME}/bin:${PATH}` This may work in a shell, but in a Docker build, it starts a shell, executes that line and then terminates the shell again, which gives you nothing. Just use `~/bin/kpt` to run the thing, especially if you only need it to build the image and not in the according container.

Comment: using ~/bin/kpt gives an error Error: ambiguous repo/dir@version specify '.git' in argument. If I go to ~/bin and run kpt then I am getting error: kpt: not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure `SRC_REPO` is declared as a [Dockerfile environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement)

```
ENV SRC_REPO=https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests.git
^^^                                               ^^^^
```

And make sure the URL ends with `.git`.
As mentioned in [`kpt get`](https://kpt.dev/reference/cli/pkg/get/):

> In most cases the `.git` suffix should be specified to delimit the `REPO_URI` from the `PKG_PATH`, but this is not required for widely recognized repo prefixes.

Second, to be sure, specify the full path of `kpt`, without `~` or `${HOME}`.

```
/root/bin/kpt
```

For testing, add a `RUN id -a && pwd` to be sure who and where you are when using the [`nginx` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).